# Pushing one array into another in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to push one array into another.

```
var innerArray = ['one','two'];
var outsideArray = [];
var outsideName = myarray;      
var outside = {
              outsidename: outsideName,
              nested: innerArray
          };
outsideArray.push(outside);
console.log(outsideArray);
```

The console result is:

```
[ { outsidename: 'myarray',
    nested: 
     [ [Object],
       [Object]
] } ]
```

How do I get the values (one, two) to show up instead of Object?

Comment: do `console.log(JSON.stringify(outsideArray));`

Comment: I turned var myarray into a string, because it's undefined, but other than that this: http://jsfiddle.net/nczptggg/ returns an object that can be opened up and looked at in the Chrome console.

Comment: You are actually pushing an array to an object, not an array.

Comment: You can access it fine and your code will work. Does displaying in console should not show you `[Object]`, it this your problem? I tried with firefox and shows `[Object { outsidename="test", nested=[2]}]`.

Comment: I have forked your fiddle. and it works..  http://jsfiddle.net/xcgv5g5v/

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? I suppose you don't want the values just to show up in the console?

Comment: The JSON.stringify suggestion from Mritunjay does exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you all so much for your suggestions! You guys and gals rock.

Mritunjay, if you want to submit your comment as an answer, I'll give it a green check. 

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There it is done:

```
  var innerArray = ['one','two'];
    var outsideArray = [];
    var outsideName = "myarray";      
    var outside = {
                  "outsidename": outsideName,
                  "nested": innerArray
              };
    outsideArray.push(outside);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(outsideArray))
```